# Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.6

```
build.gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.AA_VERSION = '4.4.0'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    ext.BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION = '8.8.1'
    ext.GLIDE_VERSION = '4.2.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-beta05'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

in app/build.gradle

```
  buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("app/keystore.properties")))

    android {
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
        // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
        // language features (either in its source code or
        // through dependencies). E.g. lambda expressions.
        compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        compileSdkVersion 29
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    def anko_version = '0.10.4'

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$GLIDE_VERSION"
        implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
        implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION"
        implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
        implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AA_VERSION"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"

        annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION"
        annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AA_VERSION"

        implementation project(':common')

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:2.7.0'
    }
```

But I get error when start from Android Studio:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
```

But when start from console like this:

```
gradlew build
```

I get another error:

```
 Build file 'D:\dev\mobile\TAgent\app\build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
   > Cannot parse project property android.enableD8='true ' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.
```

In this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: you should fix the formatting on your `applicationId "com.myproject

"`

Comment: Not help. Same error

Comment: i know, was just saying :) are you making a module or is this an application ?

Comment: Have you check that `android.enableD8='true '` is using boolean like `android.enableD8=true`?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Yes this help. After remove "android.enableD8=true"  from gradle.properties the project success build and run

Answer (score 2):

org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException:
You usually get this because the plugin version you are trying to use and the required Gradle version do not match.

Check out the link below to find a list that will guide you, it surely solved my problem
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Once you have the Gradle version, navigate to the gradle-wrapper.properties and edit the distributionUrl. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is a building tool, and android gradle plugin is a plugin.
Their versions have some relationships:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

That problem will raise when plugin's version is too new and gradle's version is too old.

One solution:
Open the root build.gradle file, and change the android gradle plugin's version like this:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        ...
    }
}
```

If that not work, make that version more smaller until some version works.

Answer (score 0):

go to  File > Project Structure > Project (Fichier > Structure of project > Project) in Android Studio, and choose the right version